# In which dimensions is it true that every topological ball embedded by a smoothly embedded sphere is a smoothly embedded ball?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I asked a question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360508/definitions-of-irreducible-three-manifold) with no answer. Here is my question in the generalized version.

> **Question 1:** Suppose we are given a connected three-manifold $M$ (possibly non-compact, or non-orientable) and a smoothly embedded
> submanifold $S$ of $M$ such that the following hold:
>
> 1. $S$ is
>    homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^2$,
> 2. There is a subspace $B$ of $M$ so
>    that $B$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb B^3$ with $\partial B=S$.
>
> Is $B$ a
> smoothly embedded submanifold $M$?

> **Question 2:** If one asks a similar question in other dimensions, is it still valid? In other words, if a codimension-one smoothly embedded
> sphere bounds a topological $n$-ball in a smooth $n$-manifold, can
> this topological ball be smoothly embedded?

I hope, for $n=2$ it is true. I don't know in other dimensions. Any help, references, etc., will be appreciated.

Comment: It is very similar to the Jordan-Schoenfies theorem, as extended by Brown and Mazur; see the discussion on Wikipedia. But that is not quite the same. Maybe you could apply the topological JS theorem and Whitney smoothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "subspace" $B$?  If you are talking about topological subspaces, then the answer is clearly no.  A topological submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ need not be a smooth submanifold. You can extrapolate from there.

Comment: Should your question refer to "every topological ball *bounded* by a smoothly embedded sphere" (rather than *embedded* by such a sphere)?

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for your edit. I wanted to ask whether **every** topological ball bounded by a smoothly embedded sphere is smoothly embedded or not? And this confusion arises from the definition of irreducible three-manifold, given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_manifold#Irreducible_manifold, which is different from this definition of irreducibility: A connected three-manifold is said to be irreducible if every smoothly embedded sphere bounds a smoothly embedded $3$-ball.

Comment: @Random, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414374/in-which-dimensions-is-it-true-that-every-topological-ball-embedded-by-a-smoothl#comment1062635_414374), my [point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414374/in-which-dimensions-is-it-true-that-every-topological-ball-embedded-by-a-smoothl#comment1062595_414374) was less subtle: it is about the word 'bounded' versus the word 'embedded'.  If that is what you meant, then it might be a good idea to edit your title.

Answer (score 6):

Amended answer: It seems to me that Question 1 asks if a codimension 0 submanifold $B$ (not necessarily a ball) of a smooth submanifold $M$ whose boundary is smoothly embedded is a smooth submanifold of $M$. I think this is true in any dimension: smoothness of the interior is automatic, and smoothness near the boundary follows from the existence of a collar neighborhood (which follows from the smoothness of the embedding of the boundary.)

Taken literally, I think this answers Question 2, but I'm not sure what that question is actually asking. For instance, the (still unsolved) smooth Schönflies problem in dimension $4$ asks if a smoothly embedded $3$-sphere $\Sigma$ in $S^4$ bounds a smooth $4$-ball. By the topological Schönflies theorem (Mazur-Brown) $\Sigma$ bounds a topological ball. This topological ball is a smooth submanifold of $S^4$ as remarked above. But it might not be the standard smooth structure on $B^4$. In dimensions $n \neq 4$, you would conclude that the topological ball $B$ is diffeomorphic to to $B^n$ and is smoothly embedded.

(Old answer to a misreading of the question: The Alexander horned sphere (see Rolfsen, Knots & Links) is a counter example in dimension 3.  There are generalizations in all higher dimensions. In each case the sphere fails to have a product neighborhood so is not smooth.

By the way, the non-orientable and noncompact versions reduce immediately to the compact orientable version.)

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but is Alexander horned sphere smoothly embedded?

Comment: No, it isn't. The Schönflies theorem holds for smoothly embedded 2-spheres in $S^3$, while one of the components of the complement of the Alexander horned sphere is not simply-connected.

Comment: My bad; I missed the word smoothly embedded. I will correct my answer.

Comment: @DannyRuberman   Thanks for your answer. If I understand your answer correctly, if the very first line you meant to say that A codimension $0$ **topological submanifold** $B$ of a smooth manifold $M$ whose boundary is smoothly embedded in $M$ is a smoothly embedded submanifold of $M$. Am I right?

Comment: Also, my confusion arises from the definition of irreducible three-manifold, given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_manifold#Irreducible_manifold, which is different from this definition of irreducibility: A connected three-manifold is said to be irreducible if every smoothly embedded sphere bounds a smoothly embedded $3$-ball.